# Can you animate symbols in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, animation

How can you animate symbols in ArcMap?  I am not looking for anything complex, just a simple symbol that flashes or changes a little.

I know that you can perform animation in ArcMap but I am not interested in temporal mapping, just animated symbols.

Comment: What do you need to do this for? I don't think you can perform any sort of animation like you want without adding a temporal aspect.  If a symbol was to flash it would be on a time-line/loop.

Comment: I am looking for a better visual display that just a stagnant symbol on a map.

Answer (score 1):

The same question was asked in 2012 on GeoNet in a thread entitled [Animated Picture Marker Symbol](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/52298) that received this answer from an Esri employee:

> Currently, animation is not supported in the picture marker symbol.

You may want to consider seeking or posting an enhancement request for this at [ArcGIS Ideas](http://ideas.arcgis.com) and I suspect you will have more chance targeting ArcGIS Pro than ArcMap.